# What function acts as .SelectMany() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq

Let me explain more:

we know that map function in jQuery acts as .Select() (as in LINQ).

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $(this).children().first(); }); // returns 20 tds
```

now the question is how can we have .SelectMany() in jQuery?

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $(this).children(); }); // returns 10 arrays not 20 tds!
```

here is my example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/4/
"l2" should be 8 if we have selectMany.

[NOTE] please don't stick to this example, above code is to just show what I mean by SelectMany() otherwise it's very easy to say $("tr").children();

Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`map` will flatten native arrays. Therefore, you can write:

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $(this).children().get(); })
```

You need to call `.get()` to return a native array rather than a jQuery object.

This will work on regular objects as well.

```
var nested = [ [1], [2], [3] ];
var flattened = $(nested).map(function() { return this; });
```

`flattened` will equal `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas -- yeah, that happens when I don't *publish* *two* inferior answers first.  "I'm always ready to learn, although I do not always like being taught." -- Winston Churchill

Answer (score 25):

You want this:

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $(this).children().get(); });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/12/

Answer (score 5):

You're going to kick yourself:

```
$("tr").map(function() { return [ $(this).children() ]; });
```

> It's the simple things in life you treasure.
>    -- Fred Kwan

**EDIT**:
Wow, that will teach me to not to test answers thoroughly.

The manual says that `map` flattens arrays, so I assumed that it would flatten an array-like object.  Nope, you have to explicit convert it, like so:

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $.makeArray($(this).children()); });
```

> Things should be as simple as possible, but no simpler.  -- Albert Einstein

Comment: This obviously wont select the 20 TD elements (which is what the OP wants).

Comment: did u succeed to run in jsFiddle? I still get 2! - this is not the ansewer!

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused.  The manual says it *will* return 20 TD elements (i.e., will flatten the array) so I misread the OP's question as looking for a version that won't.  But my preliminary tests indicate that it *doesn't* flatten.  Stand by.

Comment: your answer is misleading, many people may think this works, but it doesn't! http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/11/

Comment: @valipour @Malvolio `$.makeArray($(this).children());` will work. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/4/ (my guess is that Malvolio will kick himself too :) )

Comment: Sticking the `[]` around the return value is useful if you want to stop an array from being flattened, you need to return an array containing the array.  So in actuality, this `return [ $() ]` is specifically NOT flattening instead of flattening.  -1 for being entirely wrong, and to offset the +1's for silly reasons.

Comment: +1 for the explanation instead simple `try this: code dump`. Many times my finger scratches the mouse button almost clicking a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

[`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) expects a value (or an array of values) returned.  The jQuery object you are returning is being used as a "value" instead of an "array" (which get flattened)

All you need to do is return the array of DOM elements.  jQuery provides a [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method that returns a plain array from a selection.

```
$("tr").map(function() { return $(this).children().get() });
```

Of course, I understand this is a very contrived example, since `$("tr").children()` does the same thing with a lot less function calls.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/8aLFQ/13/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question for regular arrays, and this is the only reference I could find in StackOverflow, so I'll add the answer I came up with.

For regular arrays, you can use

```
Array.prototype.selectMany = function (selector) {
    return this.map(selector).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    });
};
```

Thus `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]].selectMany(function (a) { return a; })` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

To use this in jQuery, you have to convert your jQuery set into an array before using it:

```
var result = $("tr").get().selectMany(function(a) { 
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(a.childNodes); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `.selectMany()` but you could change the position of `.children` to get the desired result.

```
var l2 = $("tr").children().map(function() { return $(this); }).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/5/

**EDIT**

I think I better understand what you're after following the comments.

You can call `$.makeArray(l2)` to return what you are after... that is 8 objects/arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/8aLFQ/10/

Comment: why do I need map then? that's just an example to show what I mean by SelectMany()

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP was asking for at all.  What he wanted (I think) is a version of `map` that doesn't flatten lists. (Edit: OP seems to agree.  @valipour: see my answer, above)